# is it worth it to release a single language model of Google's BERT for Italian?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transfer-learning

I am currently working on my thesis which is related to automated question answering using a translation of Stanford's SQUAD data set in Italian. I am going to use Google's BERT https://github.com/google-research/bert as it is giving the best results in the SQUAD challenge by now. Google provided a multilingual pre-trained model for many languages including Italian.

is it worth it to release a single language model of Google's BERT only for Italian? my assumption is a single language model means a smaller network means less training time and smaller in size.

Comment: if you have the time and resources I don't see why not release do it :)

Comment: The smaller time is really interesting to many data engineering ops and the cost for training considering time and resources. So, I say yes! It is totally worth it.